# how to create files in android version 4.x

Tags: android

i use the below code to create file in android but the files are not created when i use android version 4.x but when i use version like 2.x the code working fine and the files are created

```
  File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FullDuplexCall/");
   path.mkdirs();
    try {
        sendfile = File.createTempFile("sendfile", ".txt",path);
        Log.d("VS", "create sender file");
        recfile=File.createTempFile("recfile",".txt",path);
        Log.d("VS", "create reciever file");
        dos = new DataOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(sendfile)));
        dos1 = new DataOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(recfile)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't create file on SD card", e);
    }
```

and here is the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Is the exception thrown or how else do you know that the file is not created?

Comment: there is no error or exception but when i check it on the device the file is not found

Comment: try creating a normal file instead of a temp one

Comment: i create a normal file but i get the same result

Comment: Ok, but did you try to write anything to it. Maybe it just simple doesn't create it because you did not write anything to it

Comment: i write to the file but i get the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can find details about file writing at the following android developer link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage

For writing operations you also need to have write permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```